# Approach to avoid loop in watched variable

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bgezTZOBlkTHUU1lekZ6) I have a controller with a scope variable `var1` and a directive with a scope variable `var2`. `var2` should mirror the value of `var1` and vice versa. I watch the variable in the directive to know when it's changed in the controller.

The problem is that this generates a loop when the watched variable is changed in the directive (see the plunk console).

To prevent this loop, I could create in the directive two scope variables `var2Input` and `var2Output` to read/write `var1` in the controller. Only `var2Input` would be watched and whatever I change in the directive I change in `var2Output` (that is read in the controller). But I don't want to create two variables as they would always have the same value. Any ideas how to approach this?

Javascript:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function () {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = {    
            var2: '='
    };

    directive.template = 'This is var2: {{var2}} <br/> ' + 
    '<button ng-click="add1()">Add 1</button>  <br/> ' + 
    '{{log}}';

    directive.link = {};

    directive.link.pre = function (scope, element, attrs) {};

    directive.link.post = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.log = '';

        scope.$watch('var2', function (newValue, oldValue) {
               if (typeof newValue === 'undefined')
                  return;
          scope.var2 = newValue * 10;
          scope.log = scope.log + '<watched ' + newValue + '>';
        });

        scope.add1 = function() {
          scope.var2++;
        };
    };

    return directive;

});
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to know when the variable changes from outside the directive and not when you change it in the directive?

Comment: Yes, I need to know when it changes in the controller

Comment: Technically your function `directive.link.post` is also a controller for the directive. So you do not want to have the $watch trigger when you change the value internally, correct?

Comment: correct, I only want the `watch` to trigger when the variable is modified in the controller

Comment: Not sure if helpful but you could use a filter instead ( [see plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NFMc9tCoF9N1aZLyJqrl?p=preview) )

Comment: Thanks, but the filter is not updating the controller value

Comment: The real problem comes from changing `var2` while inside a `$watch` of `var2` This creates and endless digest cycle. Is your intent to always multiply `var2` by 10 when changed from the outside controller? And  to not multiply when changing the value of `var2` from the inside controller? Is this exactly what your code needs to do? If not do you have a better example of what your code is doing?

Comment: I need to change a variable watched inside a directive. Basically, if the variable is changed outside the directive, it should be watched. If the variable is changed inside the directive, it shouldn't be watched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need watcher only for 1st time to catch 1st `text` change. After that you can cancel it. Also `CodeMirror` is 3d party plugin and you can add *empty* `$timeout` to trigger digest cycle. Here is a working fixed demo:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope) {

     $scope.text = "this is the text";

     $scope.showText = function() {
       alert($scope.text);
     };

});

app.directive('editor', function ($timeout) {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = {    
            text: '='
    };

    directive.template = '<textarea id="cm"> </textarea>';

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('cm'), {
          lineNumbers: true
      });
      scope.editor.setSize(300, 100);


      var canceler = scope.$watch('text', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (typeof newValue === 'undefined')
                  return;

               scope.editor.setValue(newValue);
               canceler();
        });


      scope.editor.on("change", function(cm, change) {
        $timeout(function(){
           scope.text = scope.editor.getValue();
        });
      });
    };

    return directive;
});
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xi0zhS3dI8m5Nhtxn0Xl?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve: I have wrapped a CodeMirror editor [https://codemirror.net/] in a directive. The directive has a scope variable `text`. I want to use this variable for `both` reading and writing `text` from/to the controller. Now, when the controller sets the text, I use `$watch` to get the value and update the editor with CodeMirror's `setEditor`. When the user changes the text in the editor, with CodeMirror's `on-change` I set the `text` scope variable so it is accessible in the controller.

Comment: Problem is that there's a conflict as when the variable is updated with `on-change` the `$watch` is triggered incorrectly. As I say in the question, I could use two variables for input and output, that would solve the problem, but I'm trying to avoid that solution.

Comment: @ps0604 well, I wrote my answer regards to your question. Now you gave more info, `ng-change` .... Pleas update your plunker

Comment: It's not `ng-change` it's the `on-change` event of CodeMirror. In the question, the variable var1 represents the text in the controller, and the variable var2 represents the text in the directive.

Comment: I created a plunk with the CodeMirror example, see that when `scope.text` is updated in `on-change` this should trigger an extra/unneeded $watch but the behavior is erratic http://plnkr.co/edit/IRqh5dpT9Mt21h3rGo6U?p=preview

Comment: @ps0604 Updated my answer, hope its what you need :)

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain a little bit how the `canceler` works? I see that it's called inside the canceler function itself.

Comment: @ps0604 `$watcher` returns callback to cancel it. In your directive you use `text: '='` that means you already bind controller's `text` with directive. However we need to know when `text` has real value. So you created watcher but once `text` got  `"this is the text"`, we can stop the watcher.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Here is some code that *should* do what you are looking for. Look at the code then my explanation below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
      $scope.var1 = 1;

      $scope.add = function(amount) {
        $scope.var1 += amount;
      }
    });

    myApp.controller('watcherController', watcherController);
    watcherController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function watcherController($scope) {
      $scope.log = '';

      $scope.$watch('var2', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (typeof newValue === 'undefined') {
          return;
        }

        $scope.log = $scope.log + '\nwatched ' + newValue;
      });

      $scope.add1 = function() {
        $scope.var2++;
      };
    }

    myApp.directive('watcher', watcherDirective );
    function watcherDirective() {
      return {
        'restrict': 'EA',
        'template': 'This is var2: {{var2}} <br/><hr/><button ng-click="add1()">Add 1</button><br/><hr/><h4>LOG:</h4><pre>{{log}}</pre>',
        'controller': 'watcherController',
        'scope': {
          var2: '@'
        },
        'link': function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
          $attrs.$observe('var2', function(newValue, one, two) {
            $scope.var2 = parseInt(newValue,10)*10;
            $scope.log += "\nChanged on the outside"+$scope.var2+' - '+(typeof $scope.var2);
          });
        }
      };
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <button ng-click="add(5)">Add from outer controller</button><br/>Var1:{{var1}}<br/><hr/>
    <watcher var2="{{var1}}"></watcher>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `$scope.$watch` is called every time `$scope.var2` is changed no matter who changes it so we have to be careful what we do inside of that watcher.

I now display the outer controller's value for `$scope.var1` and I added a second button that changes the outer controller's `$scope.var1` That value gets passed down into the directive every time it changes.

Instead of using 2-way binding `'var2': '='` I am using 1-way binding `'var2': '@'` This converts the value of `$scope.var1` into a string and passes that into the directive.

Then, in the directive I added `$attrs.$observe` to let me know when the outer value changes. I have to convert that value back into a number by using `parseInt()`. The `$attrs.$observer` function is only called when the outside world changes the value for the directive's attribute `var2`.

If you need 2-way binding then there are different things you would need to do. So if the directive needs to be able to modify the value of the outer controller's `$scope.var1` then I will need to demo something else.

If this doesn't make sense let me know and I will amend my answer.

**AMENDED ANSWER**:

Here is some revised code. Below is an explanation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
      $scope.var1 = 1;

      $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.var1++;
      }

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.var1 = 1;
      }
    });


    //******************* BEGIN TWO WAY BINDING
    myApp.controller('watcherController', watcherController);
    watcherController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function watcherController($scope) {
      $scope.log = '';
      var doWatchCode = true;

      $scope.$watch('var2', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (typeof newValue === 'undefined') {
          return;
        }

        if (doWatchCode) {
          $scope.var2 = newValue * 10;
          $scope.log = $scope.log + '\nvar2 watched newValue(' + newValue+') - $scope.var2('+$scope.var2+')';
          doWatchCode = false;
        }
        else {
          doWatchCode = true;
        }
      });

      $scope.add1 = function() {
        doWatchCode = false;
        $scope.var2++;
      };
    }

    myApp.directive('watcher', watcherDirective );
    function watcherDirective() {
      return {
        'restrict': 'EA',
        'template': 'This is var2: {{var2}} <br/><hr/><button ng-click="add1()">Add 1</button><br/><hr/><h4>LOG:</h4><pre>{{log}}</pre>',
        'controller': 'watcherController',
        'scope': {
          var2: '='
        },
        'link': function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
          $attrs.$observe('var2', function(newValue) {
            $scope.log += "\nChanged on the outside"+newValue+' - '+(typeof newValue);
          });
        }
      };
    }
    //******************* END TWO WAY BINDING
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset Var1</button><br/>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add from outer controller</button><br/>Var1:{{var1}}<br/><hr/>
    <watcher var2="var1"></watcher>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am doing here is adding a gate variable `doWatchCode` that either allows your `$watch` function to perform its operations or not.

When `doWatchCode` is `true` then your `$watch` function can do anything it needs to do. If it changes the value of `var2` then it must change the value of `doWatchCode` to `false`. The reason for this is that changing `var2` will cause your `$watch` function to be called again. But this time `doWatchCode` will be `false` and prevent the value of `var2` from being updated again. The value for `doWatchCode` must be set back to `true` before exiting the function.

In you `add` function you must set `doWatchCode` to `false` to prevent your internal functions from allowing your multiply to happen again.

When the value for `var2` is changed from the outside `doWatchCode` should be `true` which will allow your `$watch` function to do its work.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: The directive needs to update the value of the outer controller, if you're using `'@'` that will not work.